# Two similar SQL queries returning different results

Tags: sql

Hi everyone I'm having a problem.

I have two SQL queries that are both returning different results:

```
SELECT name, capacity, $price, licensed, cost 
FROM venue, catering WHERE venue.venue_id = catering.venue_id 
AND grade=$grade 
AND capacity >= $minCapacity
AND capacity <= $maxCapacity
AND venue.venue_id 
NOT IN (SELECT venue_id FROM venue_booking WHERE date_booked = $us_date)
```

as well as

```
SELECT venue.venue_id,name,capacity,licensed,$price,cost
FROM venue
JOIN catering ON venue.venue_id = catering.venue_id
WHERE capacity BETWEEN '$minCapacity' AND '$maxCapacity' 
AND venue.venue_id NOT IN 
(SELECT venue_id
FROM venue_booking
WHERE date_booked = '$us_date')
AND catering.grade = '$grade' ORDER BY venue.capacity
```

What is the difference here?

Comment: What is the result of each query? An obvious difference is the `ORDER BY venue.capacity` in the 2nd query - if the difference is more than the order of the rows, please clarify.

Comment: why do some fields begin with a symbol (`$`) instead of a letter or underscore?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the output you are getting.

Comment: When *$minCapacity=50* and *$maxCapacity=1000*- SQL query 1 returns one extra value compared to SQL query 2.

Comment: Which database system?  Perhaps in your RDBMS, BETWEEN isn't inclusive?  From here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp  Some database systems are incluseive and others aren't

Comment: what are the paramters and witch data is different

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  SQL is a query language. I'm talking about the product - the database software.  SQL Server, MySql, Sybase, Oracle, DB2, or a few dozen others.

Comment: @DavidStratton, and that is why I never recommend using between. Intent is clearer for maintainers when you use >= and <=. Sometimes people thing between means what it doesn't mean.

Comment: YOu really should not ever use implicit joins, they are a SQl antipattern.

Comment: Why are some parameters `'$grade'` and some are `$grade`? I suspect your capacity column is being interpreted as a string. `< '1000'` is not the same as `< 1000`.

Comment: @DavidStratton: I wouldn't trust w3schools about that (or anything). I haven't seen a DBMS where `BETWEEN` is inclusive. Perhaps there exists one but until we are shown one, I don't believe there is.

Comment: @ypercube - MS SQL server is inclusive.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx  Their comments tell you that if you want to NOT be inclusive, use < and >.   I haven't run across one that is exclusive, however.  Out of curiosity, which ones are exlusive?

Comment: @David: (English not being my native language), I mixed inclusive-exclusive use. All DBMS I've seen translate `col BETWEEN a AND b` as `col >= a AND col <= b`, which is what the SQL standard say.

Comment: Only Access differs and translates it as `(col >= a AND col <= b) OR (col >= b AND col <= a)` which is non-standard behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what I am feeling .. main difference is -

in first query you are checking capacity with condition -

```
AND capacity >= $minCapacity
AND capacity <= $maxCapacity
```

which will apply as number ..

but in second query this condition is in range of two string values..

Comment: I agree. Don't know what kind of programming language that is. But it seems that `'$minCapacity'` would be treated as a string rather than a number because of the `'` around the placeholder variable(?)

Comment: Good eye. I looked at that query for five minutes and missed that.